# Django Forms - how to check in __INIT__ method whether request.POST was provided

Tags: django, django-forms

After two years of experience with Django forms, I ran into the following dilemma related to `__init__` method:

I have a Django form definition as follows:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        if not MyModel.objects.filter(user = self.user).exists():
             self.fields['field_1'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields['field_2'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Enter value'
```

This code is ok if I initialize the form like this:

`my_form = MyForm()`

However, the problem arises when I try to save user input in the following way:

`my_form = MyForm(request.POST)`

My point is that I do not want to waste code execution time for setting placeholder property or deciding upon whether some field should be hidden or not AFTER the user has already submitted form.

My concern is that maybe that's because I misuse `__init__` method?
Is there any way to check whether request.POST parameter has been provided? And if yes, is it considered best-practice to perform this check and do thinks like settings placeholder, initial values, etc. only if request.POST is not provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [`self.is_bound`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_bound); it's only true if data is passed to the form.

However, I really think you're over-optimising here. This will only have a tiny impact on the performance of the code.